# Creating a Ranking column R

Tags: r, rank

I have a data frame (Table1) with 2 columns, "Year" and "Loss". I want to Create a new column "Rank" that ranks the losses. Largest value in the Loss column should rank 1.

Comment: You can check `?rank`

Comment: Thanks akrun, but i couldn't find the answer i was looking for in the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Table1$Rank <-  rank(Table1$Loss)`

You can also use `Table1$Rank <-  order(Table1$Loss, decreasing = T)`

Comment: Are de loss negative numbers ? If it's the case then just do 
`Table1$Rank <-  order(Table1$Loss)`

Comment: @Jsangster so neither `Table1$Rank <-  order(Table1$Loss, decreasing = T)` or `Table1$Rank <- order(Table1$Loss)` works ? then try `Table1$Rank <-  order(Table1$Loss, decreasing = F)`

Comment: Table1$Rank <- rank(-Table1$Loss) worked perfectly - thank you for your help!